# powershell New-PSDrive consistency

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware, vmware-workstation

I created a script that runs from local pc and uses `invoke-command` to copy files from Host-1 to host-2.

the Relevant part:

```
$session =New-PSSession -Computername $Thost -Credential $mycreds

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock  {
#seting a temp drive on Host for simple approch
Remove-PSDrive -Name w -Force
New-PSDrive -Name w -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Using:VMPath -Credential $Using:mycreds -ErrorAction Stop
Write-Host "You Chose that $Using:OSVersion will be copyed to $Using:Thost"
Copy-Item -Path "w:\$Using:OSVersion" -Destination $using:VMXPath   -Recurse
Remove-PSDrive -Name w -Force -ErrorAction Stop
 }
```

first time I run the script it runs great!
[First Run of the Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJnPN.jpg)

the second time it says the PSdrive doesn't exist.
[Second Run Error in PowerShell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hi3J9.jpg)

**after 10 min +- the script runs again with no issues**

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it runs the first time through. It looks like the failure is on the initial Remove-PSDrive. Its failing because you've already removed the w drive.

Adopt one of these 2 models

```
Remove-PSDrive -Name w -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
New-PSDrive -Name w -PSProvider FileSystem -Root c:\test
Remove-PSDrive -Name w -Force
```

OR

```
if (Test-Path -Path w:\){
   Remove-PSDrive -Name w -Force
 }
 New-PSDrive -Name w -PSProvider FileSystem -Root c:\test
 Remove-PSDrive -Name w -Force
```

I'd go with the second option for preference

Comment: tnx for the quick replay, 
i added the: if (test-path... it's indeed smarter...
but it didn't change the Outcome...

Comment: now is fixed the way i printed the script in the qustion